# Картинка по форме ImageButton

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Сделал `ImageButton` с закругленными углами, но картинка на ней все равно квадратная. Как сделать так, чтобы картинка была такой же формы, как и `ImageButton`, будь то закругленный квадрат или круг?

Comment: Стандартными средствами, вроде, никак. Но можно попробовать грязный хак с отрицательными `padding` или использовать к-л библиотеку для этого. И `ImageButton` не нужен. Лучше пользовать просто `ImageView`

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри в сторону масок. По моему, самый простой вариант реализовать нужное поведение - это создать класс наследник `ImageView` и в нем переопределить метод `dispatchDraw` в котором наложить маску. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7559233/2679651) поднималась эта тема.